# Is it possible to Screen Mirror with the Google Cast SDK?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, casting, chromecast

Samples are available for both android and iOS to play a video via Chrome cast but I do not see any samples for Screen Mirroring. The API that, apparently, was working is now deprecated as mentioned in the docs:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplayApi

The alternative that the docs show is:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplayClient

But there is no sample available and on some forums it says that this is also deprecated. Is there a way to project everything shown on the phone onto a TV via chrome cast using the Google Cast SDK?

Comment: Found any clue? I see video playing and casting is easy, but displaying view/screen of the app is not available. Please share if you have some new info!

Comment: hello every one. Found any clue? I am looking for resolution